# Is it possible to declare functions that work for "other kinds" of arguments such as n-uples?

Tags: functions, function-construction

For example: Can we declare a function that works on pairs? Like $f(\{x,y\})$ or define an operation on pairs like $\{x,y\}\circ \{X,Y\}$?

I tried to look at `f@@` but it doesn't seems to be what I want. I could declare a function such as

```
f[x_, y_, X_, Y_] := {x \[Theta][y] X, y Y}
```

And then compute

```
f @@ {a, b, c, d}
```

But this is not too "natural". Given what I know, If I want to compute, for example $\{x,y\} \circ \{x',y'\} \circ \{x'',y''\}$, I'd have to make a set $\{x,y,x',y'\}$, use `f@@` which would yield another set of two elements, and now to compute the remaining operation, I'd have to construct a set with $\{i,j,x'',y''\}$ and then apply `f@@` again. This is rather cumbersome.I'd like to construct an operation where I could really type $\{x,y\} \circ \{x',y'\} \circ \{x'',y''\}$ and it would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

```
SetAttributes[CircleDot, {Flat, OneIdentity}]; 
CircleDot[{x_, y_}, {a_, b_}] := {x ** θ[y] ** a, y ** b};
 {g1,h1}⊙{g2, h2}⊙{g3, h3}
```

> `{g1 ** θ[h1] ** g2 ** θ[h1 ** h2] ** g3, h1 ** h2 ** h3}`

**Update**

```
SetAttributes[CircleDot, {Orderless, Flat, OneIdentity}];
CircleDot[{x_, y_}, {a_, b_}] := {x*θ[y]*a, y*b}
{g1, h1}⊙{g2, h2}⊙{g3, h3}
```

> `{g1 g2 g3 θ[h2] θ[h1 h2], h1 h2 h3}`

```
SetAttributes[
  CircleDot, {NumericFunction, Orderless, Flat, OneIdentity}];
CircleDot[{x_, y_}, {a_, b_}] := {a*x, b*y};
{x, y}⊙{a, b}⊙{m, n}
```

> `{a m x, b n y}`

Comment: This is really nice! I am doing the [following](https://i.imgur.com/BSlOawH.png) and it seems to be assuming that things associate and commute. Can we stop that?

Comment: I tried to remove "Orderless" and "Flat" but it still [doesnt work.](https://i.imgur.com/s8X7eIC.png) In the first evaluation, it should be $g\theta(h)g'\theta(hh')g'',hh'h''$. It somehow assumes that $\theta$ must be multiplied.

Comment: @BillyRubina What is $\theta$? You can edit you question and add the new code about $\theta$

Comment: It is a function but I'd like to leave it unevaluated in the form $\theta(x)$. The trouble is that Mathematica changes the order, I don't know why.

Comment: @ `SetAttributes[CircleDot, {Orderless, Flat, OneIdentity}];
CircleDot[{x_, y_}, {a_, b_}] := {x*θ[y]*a, y*b}
{g1, h1}⊙{g2, h2}⊙{g3, h3}` ?

Comment: The order is still not correct. I guess that writing `*` makes Mathematica associate and commute. I got [this.](https://i.imgur.com/1Uqcvx1.png)

Comment: @BillyRubina  `SetAttributes[CircleDot, {Flat, OneIdentity}]; 
CircleDot[{x_, y_}, {a_, b_}] := {x ** \[Theta][y] ** a, y ** b}; {g1,
   h1}\[CircleDot]{g2, h2}\[CircleDot]{g3, h3}`

Comment: This works but the `**` appears everywhere and is undesirable. I have I'll have to change it to string type since.